# Find out if a point is in the course of CLLocationCourse

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, navigation, coordinates

I have 2 points, a static map annotation and the user device that moves. For both points i have Lat and Long and for the moving device i have the course which is give in degrees 0 for N, 90 for E and so on. How can i find out if the second point which is static is at N,E,W,S from my position ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your device is at point `(x,y)` and the static point is at `(xs,ys)`.

Consider the right triangle between these two points. It has catheti with length `xs-x` and `ys-y`, so the angle between the x-axis and the hypotenuse is `arctan((ys-y)/(xs-x))`. Note that the hypotenuse points in the direction of `(xs,ys)`, so this angle tells you which direction that point is in.

If the angle is `0`, the static point is to the east.

If the angle is `pi/2`, the static point is to the north.

If the angle is `pi`, the static point is to the west.

If the angle is `3*pi/2`, the static point is to the south.

If you want this angle converted such that 0 degrees is north, 90 degrees is east, etc, it's simply a matter of computing `(360 + 90 - angle * 180/pi) % 360`